# photo gallery iphone app using three20

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i m creating a windows based application containing three tab bars.what i want is to add a photo gallery at the last tab bar...i was successful in creating photo gallery app using facebook three20 framework..what i want is to integerate the photo gallery in the last tab bar...since there is no nib file as far photo galley is concerened and most of the files in photo gallery are of type nsobject..i m not able to integerate in the last tab bar...i d be really greatful if u guys cud help me out...i m even ready to give the entire source code

Comment: try this link https://github.com/facebook/three20

Answer (score 0):

You just provide the classname for the viewcontroller of the third tab bar. That may be work with the help of NIB file. (Viewcontroller *obj = [[ViewController alloc] init]; just like that..)

Comment: the thing is im not getting the class name in the interface builder for my third tab bar.. i m getting the other class name which has got an nib file...hav any idea